# Strapi v4 unable to override Home page

Tags: strapi

I have a task to override most of admin panel pages with custom, however I couldn’t do that.
I created the same directory structure as in strapi github repo for admin package, but nothing happened

```
src
├── extensions
│   ├── admin
│   │   └── admin
│   │       └── src
│   │           └── pages
│   │               └── HomePage
│   │                   ├── ContentBlocks.js
│   │                   ├── HomeHeader.js
│   │                   ├── index.js
│   │                   └── SocialLinks.js
│   └── content-manager
│       └── strapi-server.js
├── index.js
├── plugins
└── themes
    └── override.cs
```

### Update 03/08/2022

It looks like Strapi team decided to remove customization options in v4, so if you want to override something like dashboard pages you'll have to use `patch-package`

Comment: Please post code as text and not as image ...

Comment: There have been PR attempts but they were rejected many times https://github.com/strapi/strapi/pull/13434

Comment: Can you explain how to use patch-package on strapi v4 ?

Comment: It is the same as using patch-package on every other project. For our official Strapi demo, we patched the `@strapi` package to automatically fill the login form with predefined credentials. It happens in the admin folder under the `@strapi` package.

1. Update the file you want to patch in the node_modules (@strapi/admin/admin/src/pages/AuthPage/components/Login/BaseLogin.js)
2. npx patch-package @strapi
3. git add patches/* & git commit ...

Comment: @Antonio you can refer to the documentation for more information https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

Comment: @AbdallaArbab I already follow all the steps and it seems my changes is not working. Patches folder already created with diff code but in the admin panel the changes not show up.

Comment: @Antonio you might want to submit a new question with all the details to reproduce the issue so you can get proper help :)

Comment: @AbdallaArbab I already submit a new question but no one reply :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a complete section in the [official docs](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/getting-started/introduction.html) called [Admin panel customization](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/admin-customization.html#admin-panel-customization).

According to the docs, you can do a lot of customization options, which are:

> Customizing the admin panel is helpful to better reflect your brand identity or to
> modify some default Strapi behavior:
>
> - The [access URL, host and port](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/admin-customization.html#access-url) can be modified through the server configuration.
> - The [configuration object](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/admin-customization.html#configuration-options) allows replacing the logos and  favicon, defining locales and extending translations, extending the
>   theme, and disabling some Strapi default behaviors like displaying
>   video tutorials or notifications about new Strapi releases.
> - The [WYSIWYG editor](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/admin-customization.html#wysiwyg-editor) can be replaced or customized.
> - The [forgotten password email](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/admin-customization.html#forgotten-password-email) can be customized with a template and variables.
> - The [webpack configuration](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/admin-customization.html#webpack-configuration) based on webpack 5 can also be extended foradvanced customization.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I couldn't find real example | guide | documentation how to override HomePage components. It took me hours to search, but nothing. I know that I can replace some translations and make other small changes but nothing even close to what want - replace React components of strapi admin panel